# Accuracy of trimming/concatenating parts of videos with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am adjusting a video (with audio track) using ffmpeg, with the goal being to move the time position of some given points of the video as precisely as possible in time (ideally, with an accuracy of 1ms), by using a piecewise affine transform on the time of the video.
For this I use `ffmpeg` with a combination of `trim`, `setpts`, `atrim`, `atempo`, and `concat` filters, such as:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex \
'[0:v]trim=start=0:end=162.328554216868,setpts=1.194377385743*(PTS-STARTPTS)[v0];'\
'[0:a]atrim=start=0:end=162.328554216868,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS,atempo=.837256307710[a0];'\
'[0:v]trim=start=162.328554216868:end=173.161445783132,setpts=1.135513218334*(PTS-STARTPTS)[v1];'\
'[0:a]atrim=start=162.328554216868:end=173.161445783132,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS,atempo=.880659056939[a1];'\
'[0:v]trim=start=173.161445783132:end=197.842554216868,setpts=1.093796435691*(PTS-STARTPTS)[v2];'\
'[0:a]atrim=start=173.161445783132:end=197.842554216868,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS,atempo=.914246899486[a2];'\
'[0:v]trim=start=197.842554216868:end=208.505445783132,setpts=1.145926645725*(PTS-STARTPTS)[v3];'\
'[0:a]atrim=start=197.842554216868:end=208.505445783132,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS,atempo=.872656206861[a3];'\
'[0:v]trim=start=208.505445783132:end=212.61,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v4];'\
'[0:a]atrim=start=208.505445783132:end=212.61,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS,atempo=1[a4];'\
'[v0][a0][v1][a1][v2][a2][v3][a3][v4][a4]concat=n=5:v=1:a=1[v][a]' \
-map '[v]' -map '[a]' output.mp4
```

(the numeric values above are obviously generated by another script, not by hand!). However I find that the resulting audio track has some “whitespace” inserted wherever two parts are joined. For example, when joining a longer file (about 4 minutes with 31 parts in total), I found that the duration of the file had increased by about 0.3 second in total, which obviously defeats the “millisecond-accuracy” goal.

How could I tell `ffmpeg` to make the transitions as exact as possible?

Comment: Video and audio stream durations are quantized i.e. a 10 fps stream can be 0.1, 0.2, 0.3...etc seconds long (actually, it can be more flexible but I'll elide that here). Audio samples are also chunked into frames (not related to video frames). What the trim filter does is gatekeeping, so `trim=start=0:end=162.328554216868` tells the filter to allow frames whose timestamp is >= 0 and < 162.328554216868. If the last frame happens to have a TS of `162.318` and a duration of 200ms, then total duration of trimmed stream will be `162.518`.

Comment: A typical AAC-coded stream in a MP4 will have a frame length of 21-23 ms depending on sampling frequency.

Comment: I can live with tweaking my boundaries so that they fall on the exact starting point of audio frames i needed, as long as the resulting audio is consistent (i.e. no extra frame is added, so that length that I compute for the video is exact). Would the following strategy be sufficient? 1. somehow determine the exact duration of an audio frame in the video; 2. adjust my time points (in input/output) to integer numbers of frames? or would e.g. the video frames mess up the strategy?